# Could not find method missingDimensionStrategy() for arguments [minReactNative, minReactNative46]

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, detox

I am doing Detox testing with Jest test running on React Native app - Android app

When I configured React Native app - Android app, It was running on my real device as well as the emulator.

When I tried to add Detox configuration, I am getting following error in `app/build.gradle` file as :

> "Could not find method missingDimensionStrategy() for arguments 
>   [minReactNative, minReactNative46] on object of type 
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.AbiSplitOptions."

Following are version details:
Xcode : 9.4.1
node : v10.6.0
npm : 6.1.0
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.56.0

This is gradle file - `app/build.gradle` :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sampleapp"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
            testBuildType System.getProperty('testBuildType', 'debug')  //this will later be used to control the test apk build type
            missingDimensionStrategy "minReactNative", "minReactNative46" //read note
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
```

Just to add, I followed this url steps : https://github.com/wix/detox/blob/master/docs/Introduction.Android.md

Comment: Hi Friends, missingDimensionStrategy tag should be in defaultConfig. My mistake. which solve my problem